# Can on (release){getURL()} for as2 support chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have developed my .fla file using as2 but on(release) doesn't work on chrome browser after it has been embedded. The code looks something like this:

```
on (release) {
    getURL("myfile.htm", "_self");
}
```

what could be the alternative of this in ActionScript 02 that can support chrome browser after .fla is embedded?

Answer (score 0):

> *"What could be the alternative of this..."*

(1) Try using full URL not just file-name (*eg:* a full URL might be expected by Chrome for security reasons).

```
getURL("https://www.example.com/myfile.htm", "_self");
```

(2) Try [ExternalInterface](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&ei=z8PCW-fXAZDvgAbs26-4Cw&q=as2+externalinterface) to run a Javascript function that loads `"myfile.htm"` when you do `on (release)`.

(3) Put HTML link/button near the embedded (Flash) SWF file as option to load `"myfile.htm"` without clicking inside the Flash object.

```
<a href="myfile.htm" target="_self"> SKIP FLASH INTRO </a>
```

Comment: Please let me know the solution for local files file:///

Comment: What do you mean _"solution for local files file:///"_?? What's wrong with using `file:///path_to_file`? Also, why not use AS3 for swf if too problematic to run deprecated AS2 in Chrome?